# Throw typescript error, if there is any module which is not being imported or used anywhere

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint, tsconfig

I'm working on an Angular project, where I have to import the RoutingModule for some internal page routing. Now, I missed importing the RoutingModule and registering the routing on this module. For now, I have fixed it with the appropriate importing, and using it as needed.

My question is, is there any configuration value in the `tsconfig` or is there any other built-in way inside the angular / typescript to make sure that modules that are not being used anywhere can be flagged during development?

Throwing warning/error, something along the lines 'RoutingModule is defined but is not used anywhere in the code'. So that I can fix it during the development time itself.

I looked around the web and found some options which does very thing but I don't think this is what I need, for example

1. `isolatedModules`
2. `npm-check`
3. `depcheck`
4. `noUnusedLocals`
5. `noUnusedParameters`

Comment: eslint/tslint does that

Comment: Hi, @SergiuParaschiv, thanks for the message. Can you please help me with the option name ?

Comment: `no-unused-variable` would work here

Comment: SergiuParaschiv suggestion won't work here @codeitup angular doesn't know when something is not imported. If it's say a component that's needed you'll get an error for sure. But if it's a route, the only way you'd be able to tell is by visiting that route. We've written our own node scripts in the past to find this for us.